# Node.js read file, if exist append data, if not exist create file

Tags: node.js, fs

I try using fs.open(). But when the file not exist, the data exist.
Below is my code:

```
fs.open('person.json', 'w', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data)
});
```

console.log(data) result is

> 3

Why is that? Where the 3 come from?

My purpose is to read the file if exist and create new file if doesn't exist. How to do it in node.js?

Answer (score 2):

1. It sounds like the *FIRST* thing you want to do is call [fs.statSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_statsync_path_options), to check if the file exists.
2. If it exists, then call [fs.open("r")](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_opensync_path_flags_mode), to read it.
3. Otherwise, it sounds like you want to create it.  fs.open("w"), as you've done above, should work fine.
4. fs.open returns a file descriptor.  I suspect that's probably the "3" you're asking about.

---

*Addendum 4/24/19*

Historically speaking (other languages, other times), the idea of using "exceptions" to handle "control flow" is frankly *HORRIFYING*.

But [repeatdomiau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1493547/repeatdomiau) makes a valid point.  The documentation *does* seem to suggest simply opening the file, and handling any exception that might arise:

> https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html
>
> ```
> // Check if the file exists in the current directory, and if it is writable.
> fs.access(file, fs.constants.F_OK | fs.constants.W_OK, (err) => {
>   if (err) {
>     console.error(
>       `${file} ${err.code === 'ENOENT' ? 'does not exist' : 'is read-only'}`);
>   } else {
>     console.log(`${file} exists, and it is writable`);
>   }
> });
> ```
>
> Using `fs.access()` to check for the accessibility of a file before
>   calling fs.open(), fs.readFile() or fs.writeFile() is not recommended.
>   Doing so introduces a race condition, since other processes may change
>   the file's state between the two calls. Instead, user code should
>   open/read/write the file directly and handle the error raised if the
>   file is not accessible.

Comment: I use fs.existsSync() instead of statSync(), there are more example in the web for existsSync(). Then when I use fs.open (file exist), I still get the same result, which is "3". So I choose to use readFile(). Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't matter if "there are more examples".  Look at the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) I cited above.  "fs.exists()" is *DEPRECATED*.  You should *NOT* use it in any new code. Use fs.stat()" instead.

Comment: From node documentation: Using fs.stat() to check for the existence of a file before calling fs.open(), fs.readFile() or fs.writeFile() is not recommended. Instead, user code should open/read/write the file directly and handle the error raised if the file is not available.

Answer (score 2):

'3' - is a file descriptor.
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_descriptors

**'w'** - Open file for writing. The file is created (if it does not exist) or truncated (if it exists).

Use **'r+'** - Open file for reading and writing. An exception occurs if the file does not exist.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system_flags

Answer (score 0):

you can use "ax" mode means Open for appending. If the file does not exist, it is created but the file is opened in exclusive mode. 
or can use "a+" mode means Open for reading and appending. If the file does not exist, it is created
**and**  '3' you are getting is a file descriptor ("**On POSIX systems, for every process, the kernel maintains a table of currently open files and resources. Each open file is assigned a simple numeric identifier called a file descriptor.**"
At the system-level, all file system operations use these file descriptors to identify and track each specific file. Windows systems use a different but conceptually similar mechanism for tracking resources. To simplify things for users, Node.js abstracts away the specific differences between operating systems and assigns all open files a numeric file descriptor.
The fs.open() method is used to allocate a new file descriptor. Once allocated, the file descriptor may be used to read data from, write data to, or request information about the file.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this code, It might work for you

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline-sync'); 

     // Check if the file exists in the current directory, and if it is writable.

            var path = ("file.txt"); // Path to your file
            var data = output; // this variable contains some data to insert

            fs.access(path, fs.constants.F_OK | fs.constants.W_OK, (err) => {
              if (err) {
                  fs.writeFileSync('file.txt', output, 'utf-8'); //create a new file
              } else {
                    try {
                    fs.writeFileSync(path, data, {flag:'a+'}); //append mode: adds text to actually existing file 
                  } catch(err) {
                    console.error(err); //shows error if script can't add data 
                 }                    
                 }
             });
```

Also you must install readline-sync module from npm, also change 'path' and 'output' variables to make this work. After this if you will don't have file, script make a new one, if will exist, will insert actual data to your file without reseting it.

P.S: Sorry for my English language.